# Web сервер с функциями отладки

Tags: сеть, веб-сервер, тестирование

Для функционального тестирования клиентского приложения требуется веб сервер, поддерживающий симуляцию различных сбоев, к примеру замедление скорости отдачи контента, обрывы связи и т.п.

Сейчас используется два подхода - с применением утилит на подобии [clumsy](https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/), которые вносят сбои на уровне сетевого адаптера, и ручное снятие процесса веб сервера [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) (для симуляции обрыва соединения).

Эти способы не всегда позволяют детерминировано, по сценарию, вносить определенные сбои. К примеру, один из планируемых сценариев тестирования - оборвать соединение после отправки сервером n-го кол-ва байтов.

Из видимых решений - писать свой web сервер, взяв например за основу [mongoose](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose).

Но так как задача довольно распространенная, возможно есть готовые решения. Подскажите в какую сторону копать.

Answer (score 4):

я бы воспользовался вот этим http://www.haka-security.org/ или прокси-сервером/скриптом.

Не думаю, что вам будет сложно наваять прокси-скрипт, который пробрасывает соединения, обрывает их, когда нужно, либо возвращает нужную вам ошибку, спит время от времени (или по настройкам вашего теста - для детерминированности), и уж во всяком случае, это проще и надежней, чем кастомный веб-сервер